# Values from a table that are not in another one

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables, A and B.

```
A
ID age
1   24
2   25
45  22

B 
ID school
34  school1
1   school2
```

I want to select IDs that are in B but not in A.
I wrote

```
Select distinct bb.school
From B as bb 
Left outer join A as aa 
On bb.ID=aa.ID
inner join C as cc 
On bb.school=cc.school
```

This code returns exactly the same number of rows that I would have with an inner join instead of left outer join.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: inner join C as cc 
On bb.school=cc.school  what is that for ?

Comment: Why not use `NOT IN` to select everything from `B` that's not in `A`?  I don't understand that added complexity of the `JOIN`s?

Comment: Would it be applied also in case of different names for the keys to join? In this case I have the same (IDs), but if they were different, would it be possible to use where not in? I think the exercise should be about the use of join (for example where Inhave ID1 and ID2)

Comment: Cc is another table to join for matching the school and other columns

Comment: "_I have two tables, A and B_", "_inner join C as cc_"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `not in`;

```
Select * From A Where ID Not In ( Select ID From B )
```